# Default Exchange 2013 database permissions

Tags: active-directory, powershell, exchange, exchange-2013

Last sysadmin seems to have played with the permissions on our Exchange database so that Administrator shows up as having access to every mailbox when we run off reports (making them huge).

Can someone please check these permissions and advise what the default are? Should Administrator have these access by default? I think this may be the problem since Administrator is not listed in Full Access section of viewing mailboxes in ECP, yet shows up in PowerShell reports.

```
[PS] C:\Windows\system32>Get-MailboxDatabase | Get-ADPermission -User domain\Administrator

Identity             User                 Deny  Inherited
--------             ----                 ----  ---------
Mailbox Database ... domain\Administrator False False
Mailbox Database ... domain\Administrator True  True
Mailbox Database ... domain\Administrator True  True
Mailbox Database ... domain\Administrator False True


[PS] C:\Windows\system32>
```

The 4 Mailbox Database listed are the same. We just have 1 database.

Answer (score 0):

By default the Domain Admin shouldn't have access to all mailboxes, but this configuration isn't exactly unusual (though I would argue its not best practice). My guess is this was done for one of three reasons -

1. The ability to quickly retract email, I worked for a company that had a bad habit of sending payroll information to the wrong person and it was often needed to delete the email from another inbox quickly. Pre-granting access could theoretically cut time.
2. Microsoft TAC added this for 'ease of troubleshooting' and never cleaned up (I've seen this happen multiple times in environments where people calling MS support don't have enough knowledge to say know and enough rights to let them run the command.
3. You have a message archiver or some other utility/appliance that is pulling data from the exchange mailbox instead of through journaling. (Though if this is the case they really should have used a service account not the Domain Admin.

As long as its not the third, you should be able to remove it without issue. If you decided to keep it for whatever reason, if you want to post the script you're using to generate your reports we can help you exclude that account so it's not infinitely long. (We had to do that to exclude service accounts that had access to things for various reasons).

I can't find a technet that describes this exact scenario, but some more information on modifying mailbox database permissions can be found [here](https://www.adamfowlerit.com/2013/11/full-mailbox-access-to-all-mailboxes-in-exchange-2010/) and [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj898489(v=exchg.150).aspx).